# Gnuplot error bars values below 1 doesn't appear

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have those data:

```
Length  A   B   C   D   E   F   A_err   B_err   C_err   D_err   E_err   F_err
17  0,51    1,4 0   0   0   0,07    0,11    0,33    0   0   0   0,08    
18  1,33    2,49    1,88    0,51    1,21    0,2 0,18    0,43    1,05    0,5 0,5 0,14    
19  2,56    3,83    3,75    0,76    4,22    0,81    0,25    0,53    1,47    0,61    0,92    0,28    
20  8,28    7,22    3,44    5,46    5,16    9,19    0,44    0,72    1,41    1,59    1,02    0,89    
21  29,96   20  15,78   16,65   13,66   62,58   0,74    1,11    2,82    2,6 1,58    1,49    
22  34,16   42,3    56,25   31,51   37,14   16  0,76    1,37    3,84    3,25    2,22    1,13    
23  14,23   16,59   17,03   29,86   21,28   1,55    0,56    1,03    2,91    3,2 1,88    0,38    
24  6,98    4,39    1,72    12,58   9,6 9,54    0,41    0,57    1,01    2,32    1,35    0,9 
25  1,23    1,02    0,16    1,65    4,55    0,05    0,18    0,28    0,31    0,89    0,96    0,07    
26  0,45    0,44    0   0,89    1,76    0   0,11    0,18    0   0,66    0,6 0   
27  0,18    0,1 0   0   1,04    0   0,07    0,09    0   0   0,47    0
```

With this code, I obtain a nice histogram with error bars:

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "arial,15" fontscale 2.0 size 1600,900 
set output 'length.png'
set style fill solid 0.7 border lt -1
set key inside right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitles columnhead nobox
set grid ytics
set nokey
set style histogram errorbars linewidth 1 gap 3 title offset character 0, 0, 0
set datafile missing '-'
set style data histograms
set xtics border in scale 1,0.5 nomirror  offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set xtics norangelimit font ",12"
set xtics ()
set xlabel "n"
set ylabel "Percentage (%)"
set title "length" 
set bars 0.3 front
set datafile separator "\t"
set yrange [ 0 : * ] noreverse nowriteback
plot 'length.dat' using 2:8:xtic(1), '' u 3:9:xtic(1), '' u 4:10:xtic(1), '' u 5:11:xtic(1), '' u 6:12:xtic(1), '' u 7:13:xtic(1)
```

The obtained image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s88QJ.png

But, some error bars just not appear. I notice that is because the error value is below 1. But why ? I'd like all error bars appearing. Is there a problem in the code that forbid errors below 1 to appear ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What version of gnuplot are you using?  Mine (4.4.2) doesn't recognize `fontscale` in the first line and it doesn't recognize `autojustify` in the first `set xtics` line.

Comment: I'm using gnuplot version 4.6

Comment: If you have a helpful answer you should accept it. Click on checkmark under upvote/downvote counter. This will mark the question as "answered" and provide you with small reputation bonus. See [How do I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) FAQ article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks like your problem is that you're using `,` as a decimal point character in your file instead of `.` that gnuplot understands natively.  There are two possible solutions.  The first I found from googling, but can't test:

```
set locale
```

or

```
set locale "ja_JP.UTF-8" #gnuplot complains this isn't available for me ...
```

or perhaps `set decimalsign local "..."`

---

The second solution is a little less elegant, but it involves converting all of your `,` to `.` in your datafile.  That's a trivial thing to do using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/,/\./g' length.dat > length2.dat
```

Now you can just plot using `length2.dat` and it should work OK (it did for me).  As an aside, I think that's quite a nicely colorful plot.  The pngcairo terminal does a good job with it.